# "WARNING, putname undefined" when complie my kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was writing a kernel module that will check some thing in VFS . In this module, I need to use the kernel API "putname" which is defined as:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_AUDITSYSCALL
void putname(const char *name)
{
if (unlikely(!audit_dummy_context()))
    audit_putname(name);
else
    __putname(name);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(putname);
```

When I complied it in Fedora 18 with kernel 3.6.10, Everything is OK, the module works fine, but when I switch it to kernel 3.11.4. The complier gave me a warnning "putname is undefined", When I replace "putname" with "__putname", the kernel module can be complied but when it was running, something will go wrong. the backtrace shows that it was in __putname. Is there anybody can help me on this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See the [commit #91a27b2a756784714e924e5e854b919273082d26](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=91a27b2a756784714e924e5e854b919273082d26) from Jeff:

> **This patchset converts the getname()/putname() interfaces to return a struct instead of a string. For now, the struct just tracks the string in kernel space and the original userland pointer for it.**

The interface was changed right after the v3.6. So you have to rework your code taking this change into account.

Comment: I understand that the interface was changed, however I am trying to get a ``struct filename *`` by using ``getname()``, but the compiler throws the same error as the original question poses.